# How to use System.Security.Cryptography in Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

By reference to this link https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Security.Cryptography/

May I know how do I include this in my Xamarim.Forms PCL project? When I include in, Visual Studio is giving error as the picture below

[image]

May I know if anybody has any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that there are some System Cryptography classes that can't be used in PCL.  I use the pclCrypto NuGet to run cryptography functions in my pcl.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCLCrypto/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace is available both in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. You could make platform specific implementations for both platforms and then resolve them with the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/)

You would have your interface for whatever you need in your PCL

```
public interface ICryptoService // or whatever
{
  string Cipher(string stringToCipher);
  string Decipher(string stringToDecipher);
}
```

and then implement these in your platform specific projects

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
  public class CryptoService : ICryptoService
  {
    // implement interface
  }
}
```

To make the implementation visible to `DependencyService` you have to use the `DependencyAttribute`

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Droid.CryptoService)]
```

You can now obtain an instance in your PCL with

```
var cryptoService = DependencyService.Get<ICryptoService>();
```

and then use it. The steps for iOS are basically the same. For UWP you have to register the implementation manually, see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Universal_Windows_Platform_.NET_Native_Compilation).

**Edit:**

Since it's likely that the implementation will be the same for all platforms, you could introduce a shared project and put the implementation there. All you have to do now is referencing the shared project from your iOS and Android projects.

**Edit 2:**

Adding a shared project to an existing Xamarin.Forms solution is quite easy. Just right-click your solution in VS, choose *Add* -> *New Project...* (I only have a german localized VS at hand at the moment, but it should be something in the lines of that). Now select *Shared Project*, give it a name and click *OK*, there will be a new shared project in your solution.

Now right-click your platform specific project and choose *Add* -> *Reference...*. The window to add a reference should open and on the left you can choose the source of the reference (Assemblys, Projects, Shared Projects, COM and Browse). Select *Shared Project* and then the project you just created. Any code file in your shared project will now be compiled with your platform specific project as if the code file was in the platform specific project  (watch for namespaces!). Repeat for the other platform specific projects.

Comment: Thanks, seems legit with the DependencyService idea. But is it possible to use shared project since currently I'm already in PCL? I'm very new to Xamarin, just started to learn. Would you be able to explain in further details  how do I use shared project in this case to reduce my development time? And yes, the implementation is same for all platform.

Comment: @teapeng I've added further explanations on how to add a shared project.

Comment: Thanks.. I marked yours as answer because I have done it using the DependencyService. But I would love to try to implement using SAP for ease of maintenance. Thanks again for the quick help.

Comment: @teapeng What does SAP mean in this context?

Comment: Oh, it's Shared Asset Project.. I learnt this word from Xamarin eBook. They been talking about PCL vs SAP.

Comment: Is it the same as a Shared Project? You will still need `DependencyService`, though. Did you try my description on how to add a Shared Project?